# Second identical RADEON card not automatically detected

Tags: drivers, xorg, multiple-monitors, amd-graphics

I purchased a second radeon dual-head card so that I can have 3 monitors. I'm running kubuntu, and usually, I just pop open system settings and manage the monitors. My new card/monitor do not show up in that interface, but *some* part of the system sees them. I currently do *not* have an `xorg.conf` file, since this has always "just worked" for me before.

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Caicos XT [Radeon HD 7470/8470 / R5 235/310 OEM]
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Caicos XT [Radeon HD 7470/8470 / R5 235/310 OEM]

# lshw -c video   
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Caicos XT [Radeon HD 7470/8470 / R5 235/310 OEM]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:28 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f7e20000-f7e3ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7e00000-f7e1ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Caicos XT [Radeon HD 7470/8470 / R5 235/310 OEM]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:30 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:f7d20000-f7d3ffff ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7d00000-f7d1ffff
```

Some interesting parts of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`:

```
[     4.752] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Jan 24 17:00:38 2017
[     4.754] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[     4.767] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[     4.767] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[     4.767] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0) 
[     4.767] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[     4.768] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[     4.768] (==) Automatically adding devices
[     4.768] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[     4.768] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
```

`...snip...`

```
[     4.779] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[     4.779] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[     4.779] (EE) /dev/dri/card1: failed to set DRM interface version 1.4: Permission denied
[     4.779] (II) config/udev: Ignoring already known drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[     4.780] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 1002:6778:1028:2120 rev 0, Mem @ 0xe0000000/268435456, 0xf7e20000/131072, I/O @ 0x0000e000/256,    BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[     4.780] (--) PCI: (0:3:0:0) 1002:6778:1028:2120 rev 0, Mem @ 0xd0000000/268435456, 0xf7d20000/131072, I/O @ 0x0000d000/256,    BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
```

If I do set up an `xorg.conf` with the following contents:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "First"
    Driver      "radeon"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Second"
    Driver      "radeon"
    BusID       "PCI:3:0:0"
EndSection
```

The `Xorg.0.log` looks like:

```
[     4.186] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Jan 24 17:11:22 2017
[     4.188] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[     4.188] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[     4.196] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[     4.196] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[     4.196] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0) 
[     4.196] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[     4.198] (==) No device specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using the first device section listed.
[     4.198] (**) |   |-->Device "First"
[     4.198] (**) |   |-->GPUDevice "Second"
[     4.198] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[     4.198] (==) Automatically adding devices
[     4.198] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[     4.198] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
```

Which makes me think it's trying to use the second video card as some type of rendering helper for the first? Also, I'm not sure exactly what the `permission denied` from the DRM line is all about - googling isn't turning up much for help there. The new monitor *does* have the `kubuntu` on a black screen (is that the startup framebuffer or something? not sure what that is...)

If it helps any, I'd be happy to attach the full `Xorg.0.log` file, or `dmesg`, or whatever.

Gigantic thanks in advance if you read all the way through this.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo aticonfig --initial=dual-head --adapter=all` or any similar solutions to try and generate an `xorg.conf` file?

Comment: I _think_ aticonfig comes with the closed source drivers (flgrx), which don't exist on 16.04 (xenial) any longer. I am using (or trying to use) the radeon open source drivers. In any case, `aticonfig` isn't on my system or `apt search` - does it make sense to install the closed source stuff to try to get aticonfig?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Radeon owner but I think multiple-card setup doesn't work with open-source driver https://www.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature/

Give a try to the binary driver: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD